# swapWords method not returning modified ArrayList<String> in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a swapWords method in Java that takes an ArrayList as an parameter and swaps every other word in the list for each other. But the function just returns the default ArrayList

```
//return 'words' with swapped letters
public ArrayList<String> swapWords()
{
    ArrayList<String> swappedWords = new ArrayList<String>(); //init an empty ArrayList<String>

    swappedWords = words; //set swappedWords equal to the ArrayList that I want to swap the words

    for(int i = 0; i < swappedWords.size()-1; i++)
    {   
            if(swappedWords.get(i+1) != null) 
            {
                swappedWords.set(i, swappedWords.get(i+1)); //set the value at index(i) equal to the value at index(i+1)
            }

    }
    return swappedWords; //return the new modified swappedWords
}
```

Comment: where do you give words as a parameter?

Comment: words is a separate ArrayList<String> that isn't shown

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Why don't you use add(). My guess its the set doesn't work because there is no element in that position yet.

Comment: You are confusing how Java uses assignments. By calling `swappedWords = words`, you are completely negating the line before it. `swappedWords` no longer refers to a new list, but to the original `words` list...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> swapWords(List<String> words) {
    List<String> tmp = words;                    // if words can be modified
//        List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(words);   // if words can not be modified

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size() - 1; i += 2)
        Collections.swap(tmp, i, i + 1);

    return tmp;
}
```